# Getting text to center in a label expression

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, labeling, text

Is there an expression that can be entered in the label expression that will force text to center?  Such as the ones used to change case/replace/etc.

Comment: Can you please specify the software you are using?

Comment: ArcGIS 10 for Desktop ArcInfo

Answer (score 5):

If you are talking about ArcMap then there is not a center tag. Isn't the text always centered? Do you mean justified? I guess it doesn't matter since there is no justified tag either. These are the documented tags:

```
Font:  <FNT name='Arial' size='18'> & [LABELFIELD] & </FNT> 
Color:  <CLR red='255' green='255' blue='255'> & [LABELFIELD] & </CLR> 
Bold:  <BOL> & [LABELFIELD] & </BOL> 
Italic:  <ITA> & [LABELFIELD] & </ITA> 
Underline:  <UND> & [LABELFIELD] & </UND> 
All caps:  <ACP> & [LABELFIELD] & </ACP> 
Small caps:  <SCP> & [LABELFIELD] & </SCP> 
Superscript:  <SUP> & [LABELFIELD] & </SUP> 
Subscript:  <SUB> & [LABELFIELD] & </SUB> 
Character spacing (0%=regular):  <CHR spacing='25'> & [LABELFIELD] & </CHR>  
Character width (100%=regular):  <CHR width='150'> & [LABELFIELD] & </CHR> 
Word spacing (100%=regular):  <WRD spacing='150'> & [LABELFIELD] & </WRD> 
Leading (0 pts=regular):  <LIN leading='12'> & [LABELFIELD] & </LIN> 
Un-Bold:  <_BOL> & [LABELFIELD] & </_BOL> 
Un-Italic:  <_ITA> & [LABELFIELD] & </_ITA> 
Un-Underline:  <_UND> & [LABELFIELD] & </_UND> 
Un-Superscript:  <_SUP> & [LABELFIELD] & </_SUP> 
Un-Subscript:  <_SUB> & [LABELFIELD] & </_SUB>
```

Since you are using Maplex there are alignment options for stacked labels. Sounds like you want to use 'Constrain to Center'. If none of the built in options work then you would need to write some VBScript to check the length of each line and add whitespace as needed.

Comment: yes, I am aware of those tags, was just wondering if anyone knew of a 'center' tag.  the alignment is usually  changed outside of the expression window, i am looking to change it inside.  strange, i know.  however, if we can bold certain text, why can't we center certain text?

Comment: Center it in relation to what? The feature? That is a placement property not a label expression.

Comment: No, the label.  I have stacked labels and want the lines to have different justification with each other.  Sorry for not being more clear, this is my first post!  Wee!

Comment: No problem; best to add all the info in the original question. Are you talking about aligning labels for overlapping features or placing two labels for the same feature?

Comment: One feature, One label.  The label is stacked (Maplex) and has 3 lines.  First line center justified, second line left justified, and third line center justified.  I am asking for miracles, aren't I?       I just don't want to have to put text boxes everywhere on my map.

Comment: Edited answer, did you try 'Constrain to Center'?

Comment: Sure did!  Good idea, though.

Comment: You can split label expression to multiple lines with script alone (without maplex) so you can probably count the length of each line then pad each line in the expression by x number of characters. You can then technically control the position of each line.

Comment: have the same problem in ArcMap 10.4.1 other than deleting my legend and starting all over again I can find no way of changing the legend heading alignment from left to centre. Default is left alignment and there seems to be no simple way to change this once the legend has been formulated, although you can change font, size, bold etc. why are the buttons for alignment not featured?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same question while looking at the label expression editor wondering where else they might have hidden, I mean placed, the option:

Labels tab -> Symbol -> Edit Symbol -> General tab has alignment settings

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and figured it out. Make sure you are using the Maplex Labeling engine. Open the properties for the layer and click on the Labels tab:

Placement Properties -> Fitting Strategy -> Stack label Options -> Label Alignment dropdown to "Constrain to Center"